# 'OWM' object has no attribute 'weather_at_place'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyowm

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM("ba791ca513afc4f135cdc07cbe59815b")

place = input(">> ")

observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()

temp = w.get_temperature("celsius")["temp"]

print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status())
print("Температура >> " + str(temp))
```

При запуске и ввода города, выводит ошибку >>
**AttributeError: 'OWM' object has no attribute 'weather_at_place'**

пытался подключить таким путем **from pyowm import OWM**
но тоже не выходит...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрел [в коде класса OWM](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/blob/e35446ebe081c0b14a25dca0f7f8105836745b04/pyowm/owm.py) и там действительно нет такого метода, скорее всего, это устарело.

Сейчас, метод находится [в классе WeatherManager](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/blob/e35446ebe081c0b14a25dca0f7f8105836745b04/pyowm/weatherapi25/weather_manager.py#L37)

Поэтому, попробуйте так:

```
observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
```

---

**PS.**

[В примере библиотеки](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm#example) актуальное использование API:

```
from pyowm import OWM

owm = OWM('your-API-key')  # You MUST provide a valid API key

# Search for current weather in London (Great Britain)
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place('London,GB')
w = observation.weather
print(w)
# <Weather - reference time=2013-12-18 09:20, status=Clouds>
...
```