# Проблема с созданием кода pyowm

Tags: python, pyowm

Создаю свой код на основе [`pyowm`](https://pypi.org/project/pyowm/) и мне выдает большое количество ошибок. То `AttributeError`, то `NameError` и я не понимаю как с этим разобраться, уже все перепробовал, ничего не помогает. Вот код:

```py
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('e4f8fbf917b4cc698576c41b7ebd3b93', language="ru")

place = input('В каком городе/стране?: ')

observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()

print(w)
```

Выдает ошибку: `AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pyowm' has no attribute 'OWM'`
Кому не сложно объясните в чем проблема (я новичок в программировании).

Comment: Ваш файл называется pyowm.py? Если да, то переименуйте

Comment: NameError: name 'OWM' is not defined

Comment: Приложите к вопросу полный текст ошибки

Comment: python 13.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\13.py", line 1, in <module>
 import pyowm
File "C:\Python\pyowm.py", line 3, in <module>
owm = OWM('Тут мой айди', language = "ru")
NameError: name 'OWM' is not defined

Comment: Во-первых, вы так и не переименовали свой файл. Во-вторых, код в тексте вопроса и код в тексте ошибки почему-то отличаются

Comment: Спасибо большое, с одной проблемой я разобрался, нашел все таки этот файл и переименовал, но появляется еще одна проблема, AttributeError: 'OWM' object has no attribure 'weather_at_place'

Comment: А об этом уже писали здесь очень много раз: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1136336

Comment: Все, решил. Спасибо за помощь.